# Maintaining browser history within same route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have some routes within my application. There are some UI changes within a same route. For example, when I click a button, I get resources from the server and display it as a list. I want to mark this point as a separate browser history, so that when the user clicks back from any next route, I am taken back directly to the list instead of the button.

For example,

Route -A > Button is displayed

Upon click,
Route A -> List is displayed

Now when item is clicked

Route B -> Item is displayed.

Now if I click back from Route B, I want to be taken back to Route A with  list instead of the button. How can I achieve this?

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried [push](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#pushpathorloc) to same `pathname` along with a `state`/`query`? Alternatively, you can have route path as `/page(/:showList)` and use `showList` param.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume your app is an SPA (single page application). Routing is then just another way of maintaining application state. Therefore I see two common ways to resolve this:

1. Create another sub-route for showing list
2. Implement custom state management. In this case, when you go back to your route you would restore state. Many people will use [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) for global state management, but you are free to set up your own infrastructure.

Either way, you need a way to tell your view that it should render with a state different than the default.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Creating another route is definitely a solution. But I thought it would be simpler, may be doing something through HTML 5 History API .. Is that not possible?

Comment: I'm afraid it won't help much. You mentioned in tags that you use react-router which you have likely configured to use HTML5 history api anyway. The problem is, your JS view logic will try to update DOM in a way it's instructed. So you would need to change instructions, so to speak. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes, it does. Actually I tried your recommended way as well but got stuck. Specifically, I am just looking for route change event in my component so that I can update the state. Basically now my main route and sub route uses same component, just different state. How do I detect the route change?

Comment: You don't need to detect it if you store state outside the component. Then you would just re-import it when mounting.